# Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'string'

Tags: c#, .net

Code is:

```
public static string PrintMaterialLabelFormat(BasicParam basicParam, List<PrintLabelFormatInfo> printLabelDataList)
{
    LabelPrintServiceClient service = new LabelPrintServiceClient();         
    try         
    {
        string output = service.PrintMaterialLabelFormat(basicParam,printLabelDataList);                            
        service.Close();           
        return output;
    }         
    catch
    {
        service.Abort();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: the error shows at the string output = line, what should i do

Comment: be more descriptive:).

Comment: Can you rephrase your post in the form of a question and use the code formatting tools?

Comment: What is the return type of  service.PrintMaterialLabelFormat(basicParam,printLabelDataList)?

Comment: What is `service.PrintMaterialLabelFormat`?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently

```
service.PrintMaterialLabelFormat(basicParam,printLabelDataList);
```

returns a list of ints and not a `string` as you assume.

Answer (score 0):

If a return type of `service.PrintMaterialLabelFormat(basicParam,printLabelDataList)`
is `List<int>` use

```
string output = Convert.ToString(service.PrintMaterialLabelFormat(basicParam,printLabelDataList).FirstOrDefalut());
```

It will solve an error with types but I think you should consider some changes in your code

Comment: Assuming that the OP only wants the first `int` in the list.